# how to convert docker-compose.yml to Dockerrun.aws.json?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I have the following docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  build: .
  ports:
   - "8000:8000"
   - "6076:6076"
   - "6077:6077"
  volumes:
   - .:/code
   - /code/node_modules
  environment:
   NODE_ENV: development
   CLIENT_PORT: 8000
   API_URL: http://radi/api/
```

I want to convert this file to Dockerrun.aws.json. Please help.

Answer (score 5):

Try using [Container Transform](https://github.com/micahhausler/container-transform):

It can transforms docker-compose, ECS, and Marathon configurations.

Currently, container-transform can parse and convert:

- Kubernetes Pod specs
- ECS task definitions
- Docker-compose configuration files
- Marathon Application Definitions or Groups of Applications
- Chronos Task Definitions

Comment: I tried that but It give the wrong transformation about for this part - /code/node_modules